# Join multicast group on DatagramSocket?

Tags: flash, air, adobe, multicast, setsockopt

I want to receive network data multicasted by another application on an AIR UDP socket (DatagramSocket).

In other programming languages, this is achieved by calling (Java) "**sock.joinMulticastGroup(group)**". In C it is a simple "**setsockopt**" call.

I can't find anything on how to fine-control a socket in Adobe Flash (TCP or UDP) using an equivalent of "setsockopt" (I also want to change the receive buffer size by the way, another "**setsockopt**" call).

If anyone out there knows if it is possible (or not), please let me know.
I'm so desperate I'm ready to have a dedicated app (that I'll write in C) to receive the multicast data locally and forward it on a localhost TCP or UDP Flash socket!

Thanks a lot! :)

Matthieu

PS: Here is [a link](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/860851) to a message I posted on Adobe forum, without much success. Week-end I guess? ;)

PPS: Here is [another link](http://forums.adobe.com/message/130871) which scares me, though the question dates from 2008, the last answer is only 3-months old.

Answer (score 0):

Use RTMFP for this kind of stuff.
[NetConnection](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetConnection.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6), [NetStream](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6)